# Unexpected token `<=`

Tags: r

I´m trying to create dummy variables to identify some age groups in my data base. I´m making use of the function ifelse and so far when I specify only one condition it works, however when I specify a double conditions it shows me the error "Unexpected token `<=`"

With this two lines works

```
bb_00 <- ifelse((survey_00$AGE >= 36),1,0)

mi_00 <- ifelse((survey_00$AGE <= 19),1,0)
```

But when I specify another condition shows me the warning

```
gx_00 <- ifelse((survey_00$AGE >= 20 | <= 35),1,0)
```

I also tried making an ifelse statement but also do not works, shows me the same error

```
if (survey_00$AGE >= 20 || <= 35){1}else{0}
```

Help !

Thanks !

Miguel :)

Answer (score 1):

The valid `R` syntax for this would be any of the following:

```
gx_00 <- ifelse((survey_00$AGE >= 20 | survey_00$AGE <= 35),1,0)
gx_00 <- as.numeric(with(survey_00, AGE >= 20 | AGE <= 35))
gx_00 <- with(survey_00, ifelse(AGE >= 20 | AGE <= 35, 1, 0))
```

And consider the comment posted by @MrFlick for your logic.

Comment: If you test with `AGE <- c(1, 30, 100); AGE >= 20 | AGE <= 35`, you'll see that it returns TRUE for all valuee. If the user is trying to find values between 20 and 35, you want to use `&` (and), not `|` (or)

Comment: Hi, I am programming now as: 
bb_00 <- ifelse((survey_00$AGE >= 36),1,0)
gx_00 <- ifelse((survey_00$AGE <= 35 && survey_00$AGE >= 20),1,0)
mi_00 <- ifelse((survey_00$AGE <= 19),1,0)

Now the variable gx_00 is just getting a zero as a result.

Comment: Read the documentation for `?"&&"` as it doesn't appear you are using it as it's intended.